# Can you please explain what this command will do

Tags: linux, shell, pattern-matching

```
 abcd=`echo -Welcome=2cool | sed 's/.[^=]*=//'`
 echo $abcd
 2cool
```

Comment: http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html

Comment: `.[^=]*=`     : This means any character `.` .  which is not (`[^=]` ) followed by `=` sign zero or more times till last `=` sign. So `sed` would delete the text falling into aforementioned criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sed 's/.[^=]*=//` deletes a sequence of "any character, then maybe some non-`=`s, then `=`" (so it effectively deletes `=` and everything before).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Can you please explain little bit in Detail

Comment: @User1 Maybe you should read a regular expression tutorial? SO is not a substitute for proper learning. Go to www.regular-expression.info.